# Generate Letsencrypt certificate in manual mode

Tags: apache, ssl, lets-encrypt

I am trying to generate a Letsencrypt certificate using --manual plugin. I use "manual" because in my server I have python2.6 and I need python2.7 almost so I generate the certificate from my laptop for then export the certificat. In my case I only can use http 8280 port or https 443 port. So the command I use is:

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --manual --http-01-port 8280
```

Then it ask to create a secret file on my website and give me a command to do it. After this I have these errors:

```
Failed authorization procedure. mydomain.es (http-01): 
urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: 
Could not connect to http://mydomain.es/.well-known/acme-challenge/_6UES5rHkQ78etjN3HmT4n2l5J66vDs1nCX2APzuzIE
```

I can acces to my secret file by web navigator so I am sure the conexion with the server is posible. In `http://mydomain:8280/.well-known/acme-challenge/` I can see the secret file generated. So I do not have idea why the server could not connect to the client.

Comment: Notice the http-01-port does not affect how CA is going to reach your server; CA will always try to reach port 80. Try use tls-sni-01 over port 443.

Answer (score 1):

LetsEncrypt server does not support [switch http port on production](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/1357#issuecomment-153940848) yet. And as stated [here](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/1357#issuecomment-153940531) it will never support arbitrary ports (like 8280 as you are trying). [They say](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/1357#issuecomment-153940531) it maybe support another privileged port (below 1024) in the future.

Carefully inspecting your error message one can read:

```
Could not connect to http://mydomain.es/[...]
```

As shown, Letsencrypt is trying to reach your server at port **http 80** (no port specified in the URL means default port 80).

**Edit:**

You may be able to run tls-sni-01 authentication with standalone mode since you have port 443 availabl.